# Does android support RTSP streaming using the HTML5 video tag?

Tags: android, html, video, streaming, rtsp

I know that android supports RTSP streaming if you use the native video player, but I have not been able to find if you can stream video on Android using the HTML5  tag.

The real reason I want to figure this out is I will be using Apple HTTP Live Streaming to serve video to the iPhone using HTML5 and would like to keep things simple and be able to simply define another streaming video source for android.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't work and probably never will. However, from Android 3.0, HTTP Live Streaming is supported.

I recommend you use a flexible media server such as Wowza. It can stream HLS as well as RTSP and RTMP(Flash) from a single source.